# Simulation of a database disaster in SQLAlchemy during testing

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I would like to introduce disaster tests: what happens when the database suddenly goes down?

Here's some basic code to get a database:

```py
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session, declarative_base

engine = create_engine("sqlite://")
Base = declarative_base()

class Table(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'table'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
```

Now let's suppose there are some methods which interact with the database:

```py
def add_entry():
    with Session(engine) as session:
        t = Table()
        session.add(t)
        session.commit()

def read_entries():
    with Session(engine) as session:
        q = session.query(Table).all()
    return q

def add_and_read_entries():
    add_entry()
    qs = read_entries()
    return qs

def test_add_and_read_entries():
    qs = add_and_read_entries()
    assert len(qs) > 0
```

How can I simulate a fatal error in the database at a certain point in time, for example before or during `read_entries`, without changing the production code? It would be enough if the database simply became inaccessible.

Comment: By reading the documentation, what about `engine.dispose` method ? I did not try but tell me if it works. https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/connections.html#sqlalchemy.engine.Engine.dispose

Comment: Thanks @thomask, this seems to work. I have posted an answer using your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comment of @thomask

```py
import pytest
from sqlalchemy.exc import DatabaseError

...

def test_add_and_read_entries(monkeypatch: pytest.MonkeyPatch):
    def patched_add_and_read_entries():
        add_entry()
        engine.dispose()
        qs = read_entries()
        return qs

    monkeypatch.setattr(__name__ + ".add_and_read_entries", patched_add_and_read_entries)

    with pytest.raises(DatabaseError):
        add_and_read_entries()
```

It is not perfect (because my approach requires some copy and paste), but would meet the requirements.